# Get list from two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a SQL query which gives a list in an order based on the below sequence

```
X|Y|
----
D|C|
B|A|
C|B|
```

I want one list in sequence

```
Z
    
A
B
C
D
```

No Idea, from where to start

Comment: UNION the columns. Add ORDER BY at the end.

Comment: Can you write me the  rough query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table #data(X nvarchar(40), Y nvarchar(40) )

INSERT INTO #data
SELECT 'D', 'C' union
SELECT 'B', 'A' union
SELECT 'C', 'B'


SELECT X FROM #data
UNION
SELECT Y FROM #data
ORDER BY 1
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is accepted, while the other, earlier answers (which did the same thing) apparently had something wrong with the order. And jarlh already mentioned you shouldn't order by ordinal position.

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.X as Z from table a
union
select b.Y as Z from table b
order by Z
```

Comment: Finally a good answer. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
select  X  from (
select X from table 
union  
select y from table 
)main
order by X
```

Comment: Why the subquery???

Comment: because marge two column data in one column after it's order by.

Comment: This gave me duplicate records plus not in correct order.
D A B B C C

Comment: `UNION` will remove duplicates, `UNION ALL` will not

Comment: Well that works duplicates remove but still order is wrong.
X and Y column data are dependent on each other just like key value pair. This time I am just flattening the key value pair in an order

Comment: No subqeury is needed. And you should order by column name, not its ordinal position (deprecated for decades.)

Comment: @jarlh you are right no need to DISTINCT if use of union.

Comment: My concern is how can we get the order correct?
since this is string based data I don't want in Alphabetic order I want the order in key value based.

Comment: i can't show any key value in your question. what you want explain with data please.

Comment: as per my Real Data
X -> Class
Y -> SuperClass

i wanted to create a sequence [A,B,C,D]
These X, Y data are link to each other

From other query I get the Starting point as 'A' with the help of 'A' I want to create list A,B,C,D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a
FROM (
  (SELECT X AS a FROM table1)
  UNION
  (SELECT y AS a FROM table1)
)
ORDER BY a;
```

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT, the UNION has already removed the duplicates.

Comment: No need for any subqueries. (SQL is not Lisp.)

Comment: not working, order is getting wrong